# How do I set points on an svg polygon using variables defined by a source XML file?

Tags: javascript, svg, polygon, point

I cannot for the life of me find out how, or if its even possible, to set points on an svg polygon using variables that are defined by an XML document that is always changing.

I just want to set the path to something along the lines of

```
var polygonIwant = window.document.createElementNS(svgns,"polygon");
polygonIwant.setAttributeNS(null,"points", "M"+var1+", "+var2+", L"+var3+" ...etc);
polygongroup.appendChild(polygonIwant);
```

is there just not a way to do this?

I tried what I put above, but kept getting errors when running it.

I'm using vanilla javascript, and its going into a report generated in jaspersoft studio.

I would even settle for being able to create a standard shape, and just have the shapes coordinates change. No idea if that is possible either.

XML Data:

```xml
    <mach_name>BASE-VISUALIZATION</mach_name>
    <mach_keywords>BASE-SHAPE</mach_keywords>
    <mach_keywords_list>
    <keyword>BASE-SHAPE</keyword>
    </mach_keywords_list>
    <Depth>12</Depth>
    <Cstmr>3.5</Cstmr>
    <Vndr>4</Vndr>
    <Bheight>2</Bheight>
    <TYPE>4</TYPE>
```

variables:

```js
    var svg = 
    window.document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg");
    svg.setAttributeNS(null,"height",instanceData.height);
    svg.setAttributeNS(null,"width",instanceData.width);   
    
    var b=((instanceData.width<instanceData.height)? 
    instanceData.width:instanceData.height)/10;

    var bx=b;
    var by=b;
    var dx=instanceData.width-b*2;
    var dy=instanceData.height-b*2;
    var scalew=dx/width*.75;
    var scaleh=dy/height*.75;
    var scale=(scalew<scaleh)?(scalew):scaleh;  

    bx+=(dx-width*scale)/2;
    by-=(dy-height*scale)/2;

    var depth=parseFloat(instanceData.Depth);
    var bwidth=parseFloat(instanceData.basewidth);
    var Cstmr=parseFloat(instanceData.Cstmr);
    var Vndr=parseFloat(instanceData.Vndr);
    var jw=4.5*scale
    var x=0
    var y=0

    brJambGroup=document.createElementNS(svgns,"g");
    brJambGroup.setAttribute("name","mygroup");

    var brjambshape = window.document.createElementNS(svgns,"polygon");
    brjambshape.setAttributeNS(null, "points",(bx+(depth-Cstmr-4.5)*scale) 
    (by+dy+height*scale), (bx+(depth-Cstmr)*scale) (by+dy+height*scale), 
    (bx+(depth-Cstmr)*scale) (by+dy+(height-2.5)*scale), (bx+(depth- 
    Cstmr-.75)*scale) (by+dy+(height-2.5)*scale), (bx+(depth- 
    Cstmr-.75)*scale) (by+dy+(height-1.75)*scale), (bx+(depth-Cstmr- 
    4.5)*scale) (by+dy+(height-1.75)*scale), (bx+(depth-Cstmr-4.5)*scale) 
    (by+dy+height*scale));
    brjambshape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","red");
    brjambshape.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","none");
    brJambGroup.appendChild(brjambshape);

    if(TYPE.toString()=="4")
    {
        svg.appendChild(basegroup);
        //svg.appendChild(nbrjambgroup);
        svg.appendChild(brJambGroup);
    }
```

The variables that can be input are:
Height: 34
Width: 12
Type: 1
depth: 12
bwidth: 34
Cstmr: 3.5
Vndr: 4
jw: 4.5*scale
jh: 1.75*scale
x=0
y=0

Comment: The syntax for the `points` attribute is just `x1, y1, x2, y2, ...` without any path command letters. (Commas are optional.)

Comment: I'm getting "149.25 is not a constructor (evaluating '(bx+(depth-Cstmr-4.5)*scale) (by+dy+height*scale)')" and I'm not finding any guidance on how to get this problem solved.

Comment: Well, you never mentioned **that** code anywhere. Find the place where it originates, and edit your question to include what is relevant.

Comment: Most likely, your XML data parsing and processing has issues. Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the XML data from which you're retrieving the polygon points as well as your JS parsing function. Once you have a clean point array – rendering it to a `<polygon>` is really straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for updating you code but there are still some missing parts: there is not instanceData.height or width property in your xml data. Please add the missing parts to reproduce the aforementioned error message

Comment: You need to create a point array like so: `let points=[(bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + height * scale), ....  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + height * scale) ]` you need to separate your coordinates with commas. Your current notation (missing comma separators) is interpreted as a function hence the error message.

Comment: So width and height are present in the xml data or added later to the the `instanceData` object?

Comment: Present in the XML data.

Comment: An XML is exported from a program containing data for one to several different items that all have different values for the variables. This is just meant to draw the profile of one item that makes up the image of the assembly of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented the your current script doesn't create a valid point array to be applied to a `<polygon>` point attribute.

Provided, the XML parsing works correctly as well as your coordinate scaling the part for the point coordinates should look something like this:

```
// create polygon point array
let points = [
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + Height * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr) * scale), (by + dy + Height * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 2.5) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 0.75) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 2.5) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 0.75) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 1.75) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 1.75) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + Height * scale)
];
// set points to polygon attribute
brjambshape.setAttribute("points", points.join(' '));
```

The main issue in your current code: you haven't separated x and y coordinates by a comma.

As a side note: you don't need `createElementNS()` for svg elements unless they use a custom namespace (a lot of graphic applications use these to store app specific metadata - not needed for browser display).

```js
let xml = `<mach_name>BASE-VISUALIZATION</mach_name>
    <mach_keywords>BASE-SHAPE</mach_keywords>
    <mach_keywords_list>
    <keyword>BASE-SHAPE</keyword>
    </mach_keywords_list>
    <Depth>12</Depth>
    <Cstmr>3.5</Cstmr>
    <Vndr>4</Vndr>
    <JH>1.75</JH>
    <Width>12</Width>
    <Height>34</Height>
    <BHeight>2</BHeight>
    <BWidth>2</BWidth>
    <TYPE>4</TYPE>`;


// parse xml to JS object
let instanceData = xmlStringToJSO(xml);
// properties to variables
let {
  Width,
  Height,
  Depth,
  BWidth,
  Cstmr,
  Vndr,
  BHeight,
  TYPE
} = instanceData;


// create svg
let svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = window.document.createElementNS(svgns, "svg");
svg.setAttribute("height", Height);
svg.setAttribute("width", Width);

var b = (Width < Height ? Width : Height) / 10;
var bx = b;
var by = b;
var dx = Width - b * 2;
var dy = Height - b * 2;
var scalew = (dx / Width) * 0.75;
var scaleh = (dy / Height) * 0.75;
var scale = scalew < scaleh ? scalew : scaleh;

bx += (dx - Width * scale) / 2;
by -= (dy - Height * scale) / 2;

var depth = Depth;
var bWidth = BWidth;

var jw = 4.5 * scale;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

let brJambGroup = document.createElementNS(svgns, "g");
brJambGroup.id = "mygroup";

let basegroup = document.createElementNS(svgns, "g");
basegroup.id = "baseGroup";

var brjambshape = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");

// create polygon point array
let points = [
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + Height * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr) * scale), (by + dy + Height * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 2.5) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 0.75) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 2.5) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 0.75) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 1.75) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + (Height - 1.75) * scale),
  (bx + (depth - Cstmr - 4.5) * scale), (by + dy + Height * scale)
];
// set points to polygon attribute
brjambshape.setAttribute("points", points.join(' '));
brjambshape.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
brjambshape.setAttribute("fill", "none");
brJambGroup.appendChild(brjambshape);


if (TYPE.toString() == "4") {
  svg.appendChild(basegroup);
  //svg.appendChild(nbrjambgroup);
  svg.appendChild(brJambGroup);
}
document.body.append(svg)

// adjust viewBox
let bb = svg.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height].join())


/**
 * xml to JSO helper
 */

function xmlStringToJSO(xmlString) {
  const xml2Jso = (xml) => {
    try {
      var obj = {};
      if (xml.children.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.children.length; i++) {
          var item = xml.children.item(i);
          var nodeName = item.nodeName;
          if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
            obj[nodeName] = xml2Jso(item);
          } else {
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
              // convert to numbers
              var val = isFinite(obj[nodeName]) ? parseFloat(obj[nodeName]) : obj[nodeName];
              obj[nodeName] = [];
              obj[nodeName].push(val);
            }
            obj[nodeName].push(xml2Jso(item));
          }
        }
      } else {
        obj = isFinite(xml.textContent) ? parseFloat(xml.textContent) : xml.textContent;
      }
      return obj;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }
  let xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<xmlroot>${xmlString}</xmlroot>`, "text/xml").querySelector('xmlroot')
  let jso = xml2Jso(xmlDoc)
  return jso;
}
```

If your data source (application/API) also provides a JSON export, prefer this option as it simplifies data parsing.

Comment: The only thing I had to change was using var instead of let. For some reason, let never works for me.